# SPFX- Array.prototype.diff - (TS) property "diff" does not exist on type 'any[]'- es6 issue?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, typescript

I have some code that takes a SP List item column (a news article tagged to one or more choice categories) and want to show that to users who have a user profile property with one or more categories they subscribe to (csv). When I display my news, I only want to show items that match what the user subscribes to.

I can run this TS online in an editor and it works (see snippet https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=Array.prototype.diff%20%3D%20function%20(arr2)%20%7B%0D%0Avar%20ret%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20for%20(var%20i%20in%20this)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20if%20(arr2.indexOf(this%5Bi%5D)%20%3E%20-1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ret.push(this%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20ret%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20array1%20%3D%20%5B%22Panda%22%2C%20%22Zebra%22%2C%20%22Lion%22%2C%20%22Cat%22%2C%20%22Dog%22%2C%20%22Fish%22%2C%20%22whatever%22%2C%20%22Bird%22%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20array2%20%3D%20%5B%22Panda%22%2C%20%22Cat%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(array1.diff(array2))%3B ) 
but cannot validate or build this code in my new SPFX web part using the latest Yeoman templates. It says **(TS) property "diff" does not exist on type 'any[]'**

```
Array.prototype.diff = function (arr2) {
var ret = [];
  for (var i in this) {
     if (arr2.indexOf(this[i]) > -1) {
        ret.push(this[i]);
      }
  }
  return ret;
};
var array1 = ["Panda", "Zebra", "Lion", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "whatever", "Bird"];
var array2 = ["Panda", "Cat"];

console.log(array1.diff(array2));
```

OOTB from Yeoman theres types es6-promise with es5 lib and targets.

How do I get diff to work? How can I see if es5 or es6 is "loaded" on my ts code page?

gulp package error:

```
PS C:\VS\ClientProject> gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[13:41:22] Using gulpfile C:\VS\ClientProject\gulpfile.js
[13:41:22] Starting gulp
[13:41:22] Starting 'bundle'...
[13:41:22] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[13:41:22] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 12 ms
[13:41:22] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[13:41:22] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 14 ms
[13:41:22] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[13:41:22] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[13:41:24] Finished subtask 'sass' after 1.54 s
[13:41:24] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[13:41:25] Starting subtask 'typescript'...
[13:41:25] [typescript] TypeScript version: 2.4.2
[13:41:26] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 3.21 s
Warning: no-duplicate-case rule is deprecated. Replace your usage with the TSLint no-duplicate-switch-case rule.
Warning: valid-typeof rule is deprecated. Replace your usage with the TSLint typeof-compare rule.
[13:41:26] Warning - tslint - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(102,45): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
[13:41:26] Warning - tslint - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(105,30): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
[13:41:26] Warning - tslint - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(115,14): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
[13:41:26] Warning - tslint - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(97,142): error no-shadowed-variable: Shadowed name: 'jQuery'
[13:41:26] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 2.44 s
[13:41:28] Error - typescript - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(137,20): error TS2339: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
[13:41:28] Error - typescript - src\webparts\clientProject\clientProjectWebPart.ts(149,23): error TS2339: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
[13:41:28] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 2.8 s
 TypeScript error(s) occurred.
[13:41:28] 'bundle' errored after 6.03 s
[13:41:28]
[13:41:29] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Warning - tslint - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(102,45): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
Warning - tslint - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(105,30): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
Warning - tslint - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(115,14): error no-function-expression: Use arrow function instead of function expression
Warning - tslint - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(97,142): error no-shadowed-variable: Shadowed name: 'jQuery'
Error - typescript - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(137,20): error TS2339: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/clientProject/clientProjectWebPart.ts(149,23): error TS2339: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 2.8 s
 TypeScript error(s) occurred.
[13:41:29] Project r-net-homepage-news version: 0.0.1
[13:41:29] Build tools version: 3.2.7
[13:41:29] Node version: v6.10.3
[13:41:29] Total duration: 11 s
[13:41:29] Task warnings: 4
[13:41:29] Task errors: 3
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Eric Schrader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since an interface in TypeScript is open ended this means that you can
>   just add members to the interfaces declared in lib.d.ts and TypeScript
>   will pick up on the additions. Note that you need to make these
>   changes in a global module for these interfaces to get associated with
>   lib.d.ts

Reference - [Typescript lib.d.ts Deep dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html)

So, you can just declare an interface inside the global namespace and it will be picked up by typescript.

Modify your code as below:

Add this snippet before your webpart class.

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    diff(array: Array<T>);
  }
}

Array.prototype.diff = function (array) {
  var ret = [];
    for (var i in this) {
       if (array.indexOf(this[i]) > -1) {
          ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

And in your method, you can use it as below:

```
var array1 = ["Panda", "Zebra", "Lion", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "whatever", "Bird"];
var array2 = ["Panda", "Cat"];

console.log(array1.diff(array2));
```

So, your full code will look something like this (in your `.ts` file):

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

//other import/export statements

declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    diff(array: Array<T>);
  }
}

Array.prototype.diff = function (array) {
  var ret = [];
    for (var i in this) {
       if (array.indexOf(this[i]) > -1) {
          ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

export default class TestspfxWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITestspfxWebPartProps> {
    public render(): void {
      //something to render

      var array1 = ["Panda", "Zebra", "Lion", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "whatever", "Bird"];
      var array2 = ["Panda", "Cat"];

      console.log(array1.diff(array2));
    }

}
```

Ideally, you can create another `global.d.ts` file and import it in your webpart.

Comment: Sorry to hijack the original question, but would this also be the 'best practice' method for adding an Array.prototype.find polyfill?  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Examples

Comment: @Tracy - yes this is the way to go. As I mentioned in the answer, you can create another file and import it for re-usability.

Answer (score 1):

Also found that the @microsoft/sp-lodash-subset has an intersection method I can use.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection

```
import { escape, intersection  } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
let array1 : any= ["Panda", "Zebra", "Lion", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "whatever", "Bird"];
let array2 : any = ["Panda", "Cat"];
intersection(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I simplified the comparison to not use diff() but to use some() which is available in es5 or whatever is OOTB

```
var array1 = ["Panda", "Zebra", "Lion", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "whatever", "Bird"];
var array2 = ["Panda", "Cat"];

        function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
          return arr.some(function (arrVal) {
            return val === arrVal;
          });
        }
        for (let entry of array2) {
          if (checkAvailability(array1, entry)) {
            console.log(entry);
            //break, we have the first match which is all we need. Include this news article result or whatever logic needs to happen
          }
        }
```